# Eager loading navigation properties on abstract model

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to eager load properties when pulling the model from the database.  The problem comes from trying to eager load the specific models on the extended class.

The model structure I have is Jobs contain a list of JobItems. JobItems is an abstract class which is extended in 4 different types of JobItems, where some contain foreign keys to other tables like product and supplier.

The code I currently have:

```
    return db.Jobs
        .Include(m => m.Items)
        .Include(m => m.Items.Select(j => j.PickUpAddress))
        .Include(m => m.Items.OfType<BulkJobItem>().Select(j => j.Product))
        .Include(m => m.Items.OfType<BulkJobItem>().Select(j => j.Supplier))
        .Include(m => m.Items.OfType<StockJobItem>().Select(j => j.Product))
        .Include(m => m.Items.Select(j => j.DropOffAddress))
        .Include(m => m.Client);
```

The probem code being the includes with `.OfType()` which gives the following error:

```
    System.ArgumentException: 'The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.'
```

As a work around I have currently done this:

```
    IQuerable<Job> jobs = db.Jobs
        .Include(m => m.Items)
        .Include(m => m.Items.Select(j => j.PickUpAddress))
        .Include(m => m.Items.Select(j => j.DropOffAddress))
        .Include(m => m.Client);

    EagerLoadNavigationProperties(jobs.SelectMany(m => m.Items));

    return jobs;
```

And the method:

```
    private void EagerLoadNavigationProperties(IEnumerable<JobItem> items)
    {
        foreach (BulkJobItem item in items.OfType<BulkJobItem>())
        {
            db.Entry(item).Reference(m => m.Product).Load();
            db.Entry(item).Reference(m => m.Supplier).Load();
        }
        foreach (StockJobItem item in items.OfType<StockJobItem>())
        {
            db.Entry(item).Reference(m => m.Product).Load();
        }
    }
```

I feel like this solution is not clean or the most efficient, but it works for now in the testing phase.